# Metabolic Modeling

Tags: biopython

I am trying to identify the flux of IgG antibody in CHO ovary cells with optimised biomass and glucose input ranging from 0 to 10, but I am not sure when I run the FBA analysis what should I define my lower and upper bounds for glucose.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, this question is not detailed enough to get a good answer. Please include information about the datasets that you have. What format are they in? Can you show a few lines of example input, and ideal output?